# Why am I taking damage after timing out Senator phase 2?

Tags: achievements, metal-gear-rising-revengeance

I'm going for the no-damage achievement against the Senator, and I'm aware that to avoid damage in phase 2 I have to time it out. But both times I've managed to trigger the unavoidable move that immediately moves to phase 3, it's dealt damage! Raiden goes from 190% to just over 150% hp as the transition to the next phase begins. I haven't cleared phase 3 after this yet but I have to assume that I won't get the no damage tag. Is there something I have to do to prevent the unavoidable move from dealing damage? Am I mistaken in thinking that the damage I took will prevent the no-damage bonus and achievement?

I'm playing on PC and entered the fight from the chapter select menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As time advances, the second phase of the Senator fight will flip a hidden switch that advances the phase the next time Raiden is knocked over. At about the same time, Senator Armstrong will begin using a move where he charges forward and kicks. This move deals damage, knocks Raiden over, but can be dodged. I mistook this attack for the unavoidable no-damage move, which is a ground slam with a very long windup. Both attacks that deal damage and the special unavoidable no-damage attack will trigger the next phase - if you get knocked over by a damaging move the checkpoint saves instantly and you have to replay phase 1 for no-damage.

Comment: I can confirm that this is in fact the answer. It makes no-damaging him on Revengeance difficulty an absolute nightmare.